# Can I use my own domain name with OpenShift?

Tags: dns, openshift

Can I use my own custom domain name with my OpenShift application?

By default Openshift Online provides me with a `*rhcloud.com` domain name. For instance my appplication url is `<myappname>-<mynamespace>.rhcloud.com`. I would like to know how to apply a custom domain name (ie. example.com) to my application.

Comment: Have you tried looking this up yourself? We're here to help with coding/software problems, not type things into Google for you.

Comment: Just incase anyone stumbles across this, you can use your own domain on OpenShift. Take a look at https://www.openshift.com/blogs/domain-names-and-ssl-in-the-openshift-web-console